# Split row of tuple to two row in RDD

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I try to split tuple of ints to two rows in RDD.

```
vertices=edges.map(lambda x:(x[0],)).union(edges.map(lambda x:(x[1],))).distinct()
```

I try this code and it is working, but I want code that run less in runtime, without using the GraphFrames package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```py
edges.flatMap(lambda x: x).distinct()
```

In Scala, you would simply call `.flatMap(identity)` instead.

If you use the `DataFrame` API you can just use `explode` on your only column e.g. `df.select(explode("edge"))`